# Gnuplot barchart histogram with errorbars

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I want to the results of my benchmarks. I compare two virtual machines with each other
and have data of the following form:

BENCHMARK    VM1_TIME    VM1_ERROR    VM2_TIME    VM2_ERROR

I want to generate a barchart diagram from this data which should look like this:

[image: Gnuplot sketch]

Could somebody provide the code how to do this?
I know this kind of request is unbeloved, but I really need this and googled for something
like 2 hours, without a satisfactoring result.

Thanks in advance,
Sven

Comment: What about sharing your data, or offering some mock data, to play with?

Comment: I do not have concrete data yet because I need to know in what format Gnuplot wants it.

However, it is clear that I have 5 columns of data:
1) Benchmark name
2) Time it took VM 1 to compute it (in milliseconds)
3) Time it took VM 2 to compute it (in milliseconds)
4) Error of VM 1 times (in milliseconds)
5) Error of VM 2 times (in milliseconds)

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide data in a way that can easily copied & pasted - `dput( mydata )` is always good. It will also be a good idea to provide the code you have tried that got you close but did not work. This is not only a matter of courtesy but also helps to avoid misunderstandings in terms of data structure, objectives etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding error bar to histogram in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963062/adding-error-bar-to-histogram-in-gnuplot)

Comment: Of possible interest: [Adding error bars on a bar graph in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11393541/420055).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem once.
Here is the code from the gpl file which should lead to the desired result:

```
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 1
set style data histograms
set xtics rotate by -45
set bars 0.5
```

if this does not work for you check out [THIS](http://pastebin.com/exh3UB8G) link to "pastebin.com".

best regards

Answer (score 18):

Ok, now here's what i got with a little changed version of androverso.

[image: Result graph]

using this code:

```
reset
fontsize = 12
set term postscript enhanced eps fontsize
set output "bargraph_solid_state.eps"
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 1
set style data histogram
set xtics rotate by -45
set grid ytics
set xlabel "Benchmarks"
set ylabel "Relative execution time vs. reference implementation"
set yrange [0:*]
set datafile separator ","
plot 'bm_analysis_results.dat' using 2:3:xtic(1) ti "Rapydo" linecolor rgb "#FF0000", \
'' using 4:5 ti "R reference implementation" lt 1 lc rgb "#00FF00"
```

on this data

```
sort, 2.5953, 0.0013, 1.0000, 0.0034
binary search, 2.8434, 0.0132, 1.0000, 0.0037
sqrt, 2.8675, 0.0022, 1.0000, 0.0079
arithmetic, 1.9187, 0.0020, 1.0000, 0.0036
```

Maybe someone will find this useful.
Thanks again, androverso!

Comment: I do find it useful! Thanks.