# Gnuplot histogram with errorbars (High and Low)

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, bar-chart

I am trying to create a histogram (barchart) with High and Low errors, using gnuplot. I have found this thread [Gnuplot barchart histogram with errorbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023736/gnuplot-barchart-histogram-with-errorbars) Unfortunately it consists only from X value and X-error (2 vaues). Whats I would like to achieve is X value (average) and error bar consisting of High and Low values (total 3: avg, High and Low). How I can do this using gnuplot?[image: example of what I am trying to do]

My script is identical to the one mentioned in the Thread, I only changed some labels etc (simple cosmetic changes). My example dataset structure is as follows:

```
WikiVote 10 12 7
```

Comment: How is that not what you have?  It seems to me that the bar is the average and then you have the errorbar for high and low ranges.  What am I missing here?  Please elaborate.

Comment: The error bar high and low are same distance from Y. As far as I can tell my script takes col2 as avg and then creates both high and low errors based on col3 as a distance from avg. I would like it to use col2 as avg, col3 as high and col4 as low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a very simple datafile:

```
#y ymin ymax
4   3    8
```

You can plot this datafile using:

```
set yrange [0:]
set style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 1
plot 'datafile' u 1:2:3 w hist
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code provided by mgilson, to achieve multiple histograms for a single X value. If anybody needs it here is the code.

```
plot 'stack_2.dat' u 2:3:4:xtic(1) w hist ti "Hadoop" linecolor rgb "#FF0000", '' u 5:6:7:xtic(1) w hist ti "Giraph" lt 1 lc rgb "#00FF00"
```

Here is the pattern

```
    #y_0 #min #max #y_1 #min #max
Dataset 4   3    8    6    5    9
```