# GNUPlot: Colored histogram with errorbars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, errorbar

I'm trying to produce a histogram with error bars where each bar has a different color, but the best I have managed to is to fill all the bars with the same color:
[image: errorbar graph]

with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
unset key

# pdf
set terminal pdf size 6.00,3.60 enhanced font 'Arial,17'
set output 'graph.pdf'

set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set style histogram errorbars
set style data histogram
set grid ytics

#Sets multiplot
set yrange [0:*]

set title "TITLE"

plot 'data.dat' using 2:3:xtic(1) lc 'gray70'
```

and my data.dat file, it's pretty simple:

```
#data.dat
"A" 70 2
"B" 50 4
"C" 40 6
"D" 60 6
```

I read that I could use `linecolor variable` but I did not understand how it works and I do not know if it works with histograms and I need the error bars, I can't get rid of them.

Comment: Data please! Without, we can't guess what you want.

Comment: @vaettchen I've updated my question with the data.dat file contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Error Bars to GNUPlot Barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017552/add-error-bars-to-gnuplot-barplot)